# Using pandas group operations

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to better understand pandas' group operations.

As an example, let's say I have a dataframe which has a list of sets played in tennis matches.

```
tennis_sets = pd.DataFrame.from_items([
  ('date', ['27/05/13', '27/05/13', '28/05/13', '28/05/13',
            '28/05/13', '29/05/13', '29/05/13']),
  ('player_A',  [6, 6, 2, 6, 7, 6, 6]),
  ('player_B',  [4, 3, 6, 7, 6, 1, 0])
])
```

Resulting in

```
       date  player_A  player_B
0  27/05/13         6         4
1  27/05/13         6         3
2  28/05/13         2         6
3  28/05/13         6         7
4  28/05/13         7         6
5  29/05/13         6         1
6  29/05/13         6         0
```

I'd like to determine the overall score for each match played on a given day. This should look like

```
       date  player_A  player_B
0  27/05/13         2         0
1  28/05/13         1         2
2  29/05/13         2         0
```

So, I could do this by creating a new numpy array and iterating as follows:

```
matches = tennis_sets.groupby('date')
scores = np.zeros((len(matches),2))
for i, (_, match) in enumerate(matches):
  a, b = match.player_A, match.player_B
  scores[i] = np.c_[sum(a>b), sum(b>a)]
```

I could then reattach this new scores array to the dates. However, it seems unlikely that this is the preferred way of doing things.

To create a new dataframe with each date and match score as above, is there a better way I can achieve this using pandas' api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes there are ways to do this in pandas.  There may be a more elegant solution, but here's a quick one which uses pandas groupby to perform a sum over the dataframe grouped by date:

```
In [13]: tennis_sets
Out[13]:
       date  player_A  player_B
0  27/05/13         6         4
1  27/05/13         6         3
2  28/05/13         2         6
3  28/05/13         6         7
4  28/05/13         7         6
5  29/05/13         6         1
6  29/05/13         6         0

In [14]: tennis_sets["pA_wins"] = tennis_sets["player_A"] > tennis_sets["player_B"]

In [15]: tennis_sets["pB_wins"] = tennis_sets["player_B"] > tennis_sets["player_A"]

In [18]: tennis_sets
Out[18]:
       date  player_A  player_B pA_wins pB_wins
0  27/05/13         6         4    True   False
1  27/05/13         6         3    True   False
2  28/05/13         2         6   False    True
3  28/05/13         6         7   False    True
4  28/05/13         7         6    True   False
5  29/05/13         6         1    True   False
6  29/05/13         6         0    True   False

In [21]: matches = tennis_sets.groupby("date").sum()

In [22]: matches[["pA_wins", "pB_wins"]]
Out[22]:
          pA_wins  pB_wins
date
27/05/13        2        0
28/05/13        1        2
29/05/13        2        0
```